# Subterranean Climate System?

Tags: geography, geomorphology, climatology

Do subterranean habitat have climate system(s)? Could it be placed in any or all of the known ones: tropical, subtropical, temperate etc. ? Is it unique?

Comment: Not an answer, but the temperature underground is a consistent 55F, and some companies have started to sell cooling systems that use this fact. Google around + also look for things like Carlsbad Caverns which maintain a fairly cool temperature year round.